# INSERT com SELECT no mySQL

Tags: sql

Acabei de criar um campo na minha tabela **relatorio_psi** chamado `convenio`.

Possuo uma tabela chamada **pacientes**, que também tem um campo chamado `convenio`, aonde possuem dados nesse campo.

> Nessas duas tabelas, possuem um campo que os dados são iguais. `pacientes` & `nomes`

Estou tentando passar os dados do campo `convenio` para a tabela **relatorio_psi** e por algum motivo não estou conseguindo...

Código:

```
INSERT INTO relatorio_psi(convenio) 
 SELECT convenio from pacientes 
  WHERE relatorio_psi.paciente = pacientes.nome;
```

Os campos `convenio` são do tipo VARCHAR.

**ERRO: #1054 - Coluna 'relatorio_psi.paciente' desconhecida em 'where clause'**

[Banco de dados](https://prnt.sc/r2ebyf)

Comment: Que erro está dando?

Comment: #1054 - Coluna 'relatorio_psi.paciente' desconhecida em 'where clause'

Comment: A tabela `relatorio_psi` tem a coluna `paciente``?

Comment: Sim... [banco de dados](https://prnt.sc/r2ebyf)

Comment: Não seria um UPDATE que vc está tentando fazer?

Comment: Creio que não, não possui dados no campo `convenio` da tabela **relatorio_psi**

Comment: Tudo bem, o campo é novo, ele não vai ter dados mesmo, mas a tabela relatorio_psi tem os dados dos pacientes?

Comment: Sim, [veja ai](https://prnt.sc/r2eg9u)... estranho cara,  sei lá

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei qual é o teu banco de dados, mas tenta esse SQL:

```html
UPDATE RELATORIO_PSI SET CONVENIO=(SELECT CONVENIO FROM PACIENTES
WHERE RELATORIO_PSI.PACIENTE=PACIENTES.NOME)
```

Qualquer coisa me avisa.

Abraço

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou... achei estranho o meu não funcionar, sempre fiz dessa forma que eu fiz e sempre deu certo, o que será???

Comment: Tava montando aqui, mas já foi resolvido rsrs: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb0460/1

Comment: Obrigado @KaduAmaral, pela tentativa!

Comment: @Leticia: não tem nada de estranho. Pelo que você informou você criou um novo campo em sua tabela e nesta tabela já existe um registro para este paciente então o que você precisa fazer é atualizar o registro deste paciente e não inserir um novo registro.

Comment: Não há de quê @Leticía, sempre fiz desta forma que te enviei. Não conheço esse jeito que você estava fazendo.

Comment: @FabianoPontes talvez por você usar outro banco...